# Solar search result boosting

Tags: php, search, solr

I want to list all the names that contains "Khaleej" (starts with/end with/ in middle) in the title and description. I want to boost all the result that matches with title and negative boost the results that matches with description.

```
 title1_en:Khaleej OR (title2_en:Khaleej OR title2_en:*Khaleej*^8) OR text:*Khaleej* 0.00001
```

Applied the above query, but it is not boosting my score above 0.
This is my resulting csv

```
<? xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8" ?>
```

```
<lst name="responseHeader">
    <int name="status">0</int>
    <int name="QTime">4</int>
    <lst name="params">
        <str name="fl">score,title2_en,title1_en</str>
        <str name="indent">true</str>
        <str name="q">title1_en:Khaleej OR (title2_en:Khaleej OR title2_en:*Khaleej*^8) OR text:*Khaleej* 0.00001</str>
        <str name="_">1380621443176</str>
        <str name="wt">xml</str>
    </lst>
</lst>
<result name="response" numFound="36" start="0" maxScore="7.090176">
    <doc>
        <str name="title1_en"> Food & Drinks Cakes & Sweets Food & Drinks Dammam Saudi Arabia</str>
        <str name="title2_en">CAKE HOUSE - Khaleej </str>
        <float name="score">7.090176</float></doc>
    <doc>
        <str name="title1_en"> Books Stationery Books Book Stores Books Dammam Saudi Arabia</str>
        <str name="title2_en">Jarir Bookstore - Khaleej   Jarir Bookstore </str>
        <float name="score">5.728604</float></doc>
    <doc>
        <str name="title1_en"> Dammam Saudi Arabia  Books Stationery Books Book Stores Books  Jarir Bookstore  Dammam Saudi Arabia</str>
        <str name="title2_en">Jarir Bookstore Jarir Bookstore - Khaleej </str>
        <float name="score">5.728604</float></doc>
    <doc>
        <str name="title1_en"> Electronics Televisions Electronics Cameras Electronics Computer & Accessories Electronics Mobile Phones Electronics Media Players Electronics Networking Electronics Land Phones Electronics Al-Hasa Saudi Arabia</str>
        <str name="title2_en">Al-Baha Trading Co.- Khaleej Road </str>
        <float name="score">5.728604</float></doc>
    <doc>
        <str name="title1_en"> Dammam Saudi Arabia  Food & Drinks Cakes & Sweets Food & Drinks  Dammam Saudi Arabia Dammam Saudi Arabia Dammam Saudi Arabia</str>
        <str name="title2_en">CAKE HOUSE CAKE HOUSE - 91 CAKE HOUSE - Mazroeyah CAKE HOUSE - Khaleej</str>
        <float name="score">4.3670316</float></doc>
    <doc>
        <str name="title1_en"> Al-Hasa Saudi Arabia  Electronics Televisions Electronics Cameras Electronics Computer & Accessories Electronics Mobile Phones Electronics Media Players Electronics Networking Electronics Land Phones Electronics  Al-Hasa Saudi Arabia Al-Hasa Saudi Arabia Al-Hasa Saudi Arabia</str>
        <str name="title2_en">Al-Baha Trading co. Al-Baha Trading Co.- Ali bin Aby Taleb Street Al-Baha Trading Co.- Dahran Road Al-Baha Trading Co.- Khaleej Road</str>
        <float name="score">3.0054595</float></doc>
    <doc>
        <str name="title1_en"> Education Schools Education Male School Schools Education Dammam Saudi Arabia</str>
        <str name="title2_en">Rowad AlKhaleej International Schools </str>
        <float name="score">0.15684171</float></doc>
    <doc>
        <str name="title1_en"> Dammam Saudi Arabia  Education Schools Education Male School Schools Education </str>
        <str name="title2_en">Rowad AlKhaleej International Schools</str>
        <float name="score">0.15684171</float></doc>
    <doc>
        <str name="title1_en"> Malls Shopping Dammam Saudi Arabia</str>
        <str name="title2_en">Shate'e Mall </str>
        <float name="score">0.01568417</float></doc>
    <doc>
        <str name="title1_en"> Dammam Saudi Arabia  Malls Shopping </str>
        <str name="title2_en">Shate'e Mall</str>
        <float name="score">0.01568417</float></doc>
</result>
```

Answer (score 1):

WildcardQuery affects scoring : fields that match the WildcardQuery each have an equal boost to the score added by that match. So it seems normal that your results are not boosted as you expect. 
See :`CONSTANT_SCORE_AUTO_REWRITE_DEFAULT`.